# How to perform operation on elements of list which depend on previous elements?

Tags: python, list

Using map can do operations of current element in list:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6];


print(list(map(lambda x: x*2, l)))  
# gives [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

In above, multiply by 2 is done for all elements in l. But how to mulitiply by 2 an element in l, only if previous value in l is odd? Can use map for this?

For example to get:

```
[1,4,3,8,5,12] % only 2, 4 and 6 from l are multiplyied by 2, because before them there are odd numbers 1,3,5.
```

Comment: Do you mean multiplied by 2? You are doing `x*2` which is multiplication. `x**2` is to the power of.

Comment: Yes, multiply by 2. Sorry. I edited question.

Comment: @aj8uppal That is not the problem anyways. The problem is to perform an operation based on the previous element. I don't think there are any clean pythonic ways to do it. You will probably need to iterate using explicit indexing. I don't think there is any utility to get item before or after the current. OP is also not clear on bounduary conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` if you do it on an `enumerate`d version:

```
print(list(map(lambda index,x: x*2 if index > 1 and l[index-1] & 1 else x, enumerate(l))))
```

However, as you might have noticed, that's really not very readable. It's better to just use a list comprehension or a for loop:

```
print([x*2 if index > 1 and l[index-1] & 1 else x
       for index, x in enumerate(l)])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` in combination with `map`:

```
print(l[:1] + list(map(lambda x: x[1]*2 if x[0] & 1 else x[1], zip(l, l[1:]))))
```

Note that I had to explicitly prepend the first element of the list because it has no previous element to test.

Comment: That will skip the first element in `l`, will it not? (Granted, OP wasn't exactly clear about what they wanted in that case.)

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` the list along with a sliced copy of the list to pair all of the items:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> zip(l, l[1:])
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something callable to track your previous value. Depending on how abstract you want this:

```
prev = [0]
def callback(x):
    val = ((prev[0] % 2) + 1) * x
    prev[0] = x
    return val

print list(map(callback, l))
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise that it was probably just a trivial example, but thought it worth mentioning that in your example case the condition *"if the previous value is odd"* is the same as *"if the current value is even"* (at least for your sample input). In which case I would just use

```
print([x if x&1 else x*2 for x in l])
```

For the more general case and assuming the condition may be more complex than just "previous item is odd", I would take a few lines to express the solution clearly. Python's [generators](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#generators) are a good fit:

```
>>> def double_if_prev_odd(l):
...     prev_odd = False # initial condition for 1st element
...     for x in l:
...             yield x**2 if prev_odd else x
...             prev_odd = x&1
...
>>> list(double_if_prev_odd(l))
[1, 4, 3, 16, 5, 36]
```